# LQI for angular speed control in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, control-theory, linear-control

With the following state space system and setting for the **Linear Quadratic Integrator** (LQI) `Q = diag([1,1,1])` and `r = 1`; for optimal gains computation, the system is not reaching the desired output by an unit step input (reaching `0.5` as shown in image below), strangely when I set the C matrix to measure position `C = [1 0]`, the output does track the reference input.

```
Jm  = 0.008; % Rotor inertia
dm  = 0.015; % Damping

A = [0 1;0 -dm/Jm];
B = [0;1/Jm];
C = [0 1];
D =0;
sys  = ss(A,B,C,D);

Q = diag([1,1,1]);
r = 1;

[K,S,e] = lqi(sys,Q,r,0);


Aa = [A [0;0];-C 0];
Ba = [B;0];
Ca = [C 0];

Bi = [0;0;1];
sys_cl = ss(Aa-Ba*K,Bi,Ca,D);
step(sys_cl);
```

[image: Response for speed control]

[image: Response for position control]

Is it ppossible that the corresponding Q and r values to be off causing this?

Comment: Why don't you post this on stackoverflow?

Comment: Are you taking print-screens from Matlab?  If you save in PNG, it should be possible to have much nicer-looking plots than this. Also, why don't you choose better titles for the plots? Also, LQI stands for... ?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Linear Quadratic Integrator, thank you for the edit.

Comment: You provide neither a reference nor a brief explanation of what you mean by LQI.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in controlling angular speed (not the angle itself) your model is first order. You don't need the integrator (and in fact you are not measuring it anyway when $C = [0 ~~ 1]$ and it is not observable).

When you set $C = [1 ~~ 0]$ you are basically controlling the angle, not angular speed.

Comment: I see now that rank(obsv(A,[0 1])) = 1, Yet I still dont understand the physical sense of it, why measuring speed only makes the system unobservable?

Comment: Observability means one may reconstruct the states initial position and therefore current position by observation of the output. Only by looking for the angular speed, you may not find out where does the system come from, which is not helpful for multivariable control.

Comment: Furthremore, you MUST discern between output matrix $C$ and integration matrix $C_i$. The former corresponds to the sensor matrix, for example, the angular position. The latter corresponds to matrix you wish to track, for example, the angular speed.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto For integration matrix C_i you mean the one used for the output of the closed loop system? But the lqi gains are computed with respect to the original C, in this case, [1 0]

Comment: The LQI MUST utilize the tracking output $C_i$.